# ArcMap extremely slow to load point data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, performance, windows-10, arcgis-10.8

It is taking ArcMap an extremely long time to load point data.  For example, up to five minutes to load (add to the canvas initially) a shapefile of 44 points.

The issue affects all point data regardless of size and does not affect any other data (eg. polyline shapefile with 4224895 vertices loads immediately).

I am using an MSI laptop with 32GB of RAM, an 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11800H processor and an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 GPU.  I had to disable ArcMap's use of the GPU in the NVIDIA control panel because it was continuously crashing when enabled.

OS is Windows 10 Home and I am using ArcGIS Desktop v. 10.8.1.

Would anyone know which settings are causing this issue or how to resolve it?

Comment: Is that for all point data or just for a specific point dataset ?

Comment: Also does it affect only shapefile or other format as well ?

Comment: 10.3 is *very* old software (10.3.1 has been Retired for 10 months). You don't say what OS you're using, but 10.3 certainly wasn't built for that current platform. Driver issues are the most likely cause, and very difficult to diagnose and repair.

Comment: @Vince I recently upgraded from 10.3 to 10.8 on the same window 7 system, if anything it's slower now...

Comment: Great. 10.8.1 is the latest 10.8 version, and it's definitely a driver issue (probably between old/unsupported Windows 7 and current hardware).

Comment: @J.R, I have edited to answer your question - it only affects point data, no other type of shapefile

Comment: @Vince apologies, I am actually using 10.8.1

Comment: Does "Load point data" mean *display* in the map canvas, or open the table, or add to the canvas initially?  Have you tried changing the marker symbology?  Have you tried converting the shapefile to file geodatabase, and is the problem the same?

Comment: @Vince thanks so much for the suggestion - just tried converting and then loading as geodatabase, unfortunately there is no difference.  And yes I mean load to the canvas initially. There is no symbology attached it is just loading to the default point symbol.

Comment: Tech Support might have ideas, but the fact that you had to disable CUDA use has you far, far outside usual behavior. I try to avoid it, but I can render 40M points in 5 minutes.

Comment: @Vince ok will do - pretty jealous of your render time right now